# Open links in different browser depending on the application in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I would like for applications to open links in different browsers. For example, links in slack should be opened in chrome, but links in discord should open in firefox. Is there a way to configure this on Windows 10?

Something like [Choosy](https://www.choosyosx.com/) for mac os x.

Comment: What you want is not natively feasible. I keep different links as favorites in different browsers. That works.

Answer (score 0):

A bookmark has a browser extension (htm).

A single Extension can only be associated with a single App.

So for example,  I have htm and html associated with Chromium Edge (not any other browser).

So you cannot open up a single extension with multiple browsers.  I keep multiple favorites in multiple browsers when I need to use multiple browsers.

[image: Extensions associated with apps]

Comment: Using favourites does not solve my issue. I would like to click on links in applications and have them open a different browser based on the application in which the link is clicked.

Comment: As I noted, you cannot do that by clicking on links, because of the one to one relationship between link and app. I am not sure why entering favorites in browsers do not work for you - it does for em.

Comment: You may have to figure out how to have the application you are using open the browser of your choice so that it will in turn open the link. I think that could be a bit difficult, but that may be the only road open to you. From the pure browser point of view, the one to one relationship takes precedence.